# Open in same view controller as closed on (swift)

Tags: swift, view, controller, save, nsuserdefaults

I am making a simple fact app (In swift) and all the facts are in separate view controllers and when the user closes the app, it all goes to the main page and you have to start from fact 1 again.

I want to know how to save what view controller the user was on when they closed it and when they continue through the facts again,it starts on that fact. Thanks:) also if someone makes a video i think it will get enough views to start a YT channel

Comment: Did you try something? What failed? How did you try to implement this?

Comment: I'm trying to make a fact app and on the main page it says fact and you click it and it goes to first fact on separate view controller, when on separate view controller you click next to see new fact on new view controller.But when the user closes the app the main view loads and you click fact, it goes to first fact instead of the last one you closed the app on. How can i get it to go to the fact you closed the app on instead of the 1st one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated to Swift 5**

You can use `UserDefaults` which will remember your last `ViewController`.

First of all, you have to store some integer when you load any view like shown below:

**FirstView.swift**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(0, forKey: "View")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(1, forKey: "View")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Now In your **AppDelegate.swift** read that stored values and load the ViewController related to that Integer this way:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let viewCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "View")
    var VC = UIViewController()
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    println(viewCount)
    if viewCount == 0 {
        //FirstView should initiate
        VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First") as! ViewController
    } else if viewCount == 1 {
        //SecondView should inititate
        VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second") as! SecondViewController
    } else {
        //ThirdView Should Initiate
        VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Third") as! ThirdViewController
    }

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.window?.rootViewController = VC

    return true
}
```

Check out [THIS](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Load-Last-ViewController-at-start) sample project for more Info.

Comment: THANK U SOOO MUCH. i have been searching for a while:)